# About the /Catalog object in a pdf file

Tags: pdf

I see the following objects in a pdf file. It is clear that 16875 is the top /Pages and 16876 is a dictionary of all the link destinations in the pdf. I only see one object with the type /Catalog in the pdf.

Is it always the case that there is only one /Catalog object which contains a pointer to a top /Pages object and a pointer to an object of all the link destinations?

```
119038 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog
/Pages 16875 0 R
/Dests 16876 0 R
/MarkInfo <</Type /MarkInfo
/Marked true>>
/StructTreeRoot 16877 0 R>>
endobj
```

```
16876 0 obj
<</05_preface [11 0 R /XYZ 34.005386 763.99994 0]
/sec1 [339 0 R /XYZ 34.005386 400.67438 0]
/fn1 [339 0 R /XYZ 339.52963 268.5553 0]
...
```

```
16875 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Count 1603
/Kids [16871 0 R 16872 0 R 16873 0 R 16874 0 R]>>
endobj
```

Comment: Does the PDF spec there is geenerally one and only one `/Catalog`? I don't find such a statement in the PDF spec. If there is, would you please let me know where it is? What other keys must be in a /Catalog object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it always the case that there is only one /Catalog object which contains a pointer to a top /Pages object and a pointer to an object of all the link destinations?

There can be an arbitrary number of dictionaries with type **Catalog** in a PDF. The one that is relevant is the one referenced as **Root** from the trailer.

Beware, though, the **Dests** only contain the *named* destinations, not necessarily all of them.